# Bar chart corruption when plotting multiple subplots in MATPLOTLIB

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created a class that allows a user to add several charts to a MATPLOTLIB window. These can be either a line chart or a bar chart. It also has the feature that when a chart has already been added to the window (as identified from rowID) rather than draw a new plot it will replace the data in the old plot. ie it allows for updates (animation)

This works grand for the line plot but I get corruption when plotting several bar charts. The class looks like:

```
  import math

  class TFrmPlot():

    def __init__(self, point_lists, deleteCallback, plotType, rowID):                    
            import matplotlib 
            matplotlib.interactive( True )
            matplotlib.use( 'WXAgg' )  

            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
            self.plt = plt
            self.fig = plt.figure()      
            self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', self.on_close)    

            import matplotlib.axes as ax    
            self.ax = ax

            self.deleteCallback = deleteCallback
            self.chartArray = []              
            self.addChart(point_lists, plotType, rowID)

        def close(self):    
            self.plt.close('all')
            #self.fig.close()

        def replaceChartDataIfChartExists(self, point_lists, rowID):
            if rowID==0:
                pass
            for chart in self.chartArray:
                for plot in chart.plots:
                    if plot.rowID == rowID:
                        plot.points = point_lists                               
                        if plot.plotType=="Point":                         
                            plot.plotItem.set_data(point_lists[0],point_lists[1])                          
                            chart.subPlot.draw_artist(plot.plotItem)                        
                            self.fig.canvas.blit(chart.subPlot.bbox) 
                        else:                      
                            for rect, h in zip(plot.plotItem, point_lists[1]):
                                rect.set_height(h)   
                        chart.subPlot.relim()                     
                        chart.subPlot.autoscale_view(True,True,True)                                                       
                        self.plt.draw()
                        return True
            return False    

        def addChart(self, point_lists, plotType, rowID):
            self.chartArray.append(TChart(rowID,plotType,point_lists))
            self._drawAll() 

        def addPlot(self, point_lists, plotType, rowID):           
            chartNum = len(self.chartArray)
            self.chartArray[chartNum-1].plots.append(TPlot(rowID,plotType,point_lists))  
            self._drawAll()

        def on_close(self, event):
            self.deleteCallback()

        def _drawAll(self):     
            self.plt.clf()
            numSubPlots = len(self.chartArray)
            numCols = self._noCols(numSubPlots)
            IndexConverter = TIndexConverter(numCols)
            subPlot = None
            for chartIndex in range(0,numSubPlots):
                if numSubPlots==1:                
                    subPlot = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
                elif numSubPlots==2:                             
                    subPlot = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,chartIndex+1)
                else:
                    subPlot = self.fig.add_subplot(2,numCols,IndexConverter._getSubPlotIndex(chartIndex))
                subPlot.relim()           
                subPlot.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
                self.chartArray[chartIndex].subPlot = subPlot
                self._drawSubs(self.chartArray[chartIndex])                   
            self.plt.show() 

        def _drawSubs(self, chart):
            for plot in chart.plots:
                if plot.plotType=="Point":          
                    chart.subPlot.plot(plot.points[0],plot.points[1])
                    plot.plotItem = chart.subPlot.lines[len(chart.subPlot.lines)-1]
                else:
                    kwargs = {"alpha":0.5}
                    plot.plotItem = chart.subPlot.bar(plot.points[0],plot.points[1], width=self._calculateleastDiff(plot.points[0]), **kwargs)     

        def _noCols(self, numSubPlots):
            return math.ceil(float(numSubPlots)/2.0)  

        def _calculateleastDiff(self, xValues):
            xValues2 = sorted(xValues)
            leastDiff = None
            lastValue = None
            for value in xValues2:
                if lastValue is not None: 
                    diff = value-lastValue            
                    if leastDiff is None or diff < leastDiff:
                        leastDiff = diff
                lastValue = value 
            return leastDiff
```

This is a bit long so to summarise:

addChart -- basically adds a new subplot

addPlot -- adds a new line or bar to an existing subplot

replaceChartDataIfChartExists -- refreshes the data if the ID already exists

The dummy data that I'm using just plots a positive gradient and a negative gradient line in succession. My plots however can get into a state where one/some or all of the bar plots become corrupted. It looks almost like the x/y axis has been rotated, with the individual bars not starting from the x-axis. The issue is intermittent; sometimes I will get several plots as expected. Once a plot becomes corrupted all future updates remain corrupted.

[image: Corrupted Data Plot]

As requested, the remaining code:

```
class TIndexConverter():    
    def __init__(self, numCols):                                      
        self.evenCounter = 0
        self.oddCounter = numCols

    def _getSubPlotIndex(self, arrayIndex):
        if arrayIndex%2==0:
            self.evenCounter += 1
            return self.evenCounter
        else:        
            self.oddCounter += 1
            return self.oddCounter


class TChart():
    def __init__(self, rowID, plotType, point_lists):
        self.subPlot = None
        self.plots = [TPlot(rowID, plotType, point_lists)]

class TPlot():
    def __init__(self, rowID, plotType, point_lists):                     
        self.plotItem = None        
        self.plotType = plotType  
        self.rowID = rowID           
        self.points = point_lists
```

some client code:

```
def _updateData(self, state, data): 
    if self.plot is not None:
        if not self.plot.replaceChartDataIfChartExists(data, state.comm.rowID):
            if self.createNewChart == True:
                self.plot.addChart(data, state.setting.plotType, state.comm.rowID)    
            else:
                self.plot.addPlot(data, state.setting.plotType, state.comm.rowID)
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what this corruption looks like?

Comment: Sorry. It won't let me post since my rep is too low. I also posted on the matplotlib user forums. I have an image there: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Bar-chart-corruption-when-plotting-multiple-subplots-in-MATPLOTLIB-td40023.html

Comment: can you also post the code for `Tchart` as well?

Comment: can you also post an example usage?  It is easier to sort out what the problem is if we don't have to guess what arguments do/need to be

Comment: Can you also provide an example of what `state` and `data` are?  What class is `_updateData` a member of?

Comment: Data is just the points list. This class is part of an MVC type GUI. The state is just a model state; all I'm using from it is a unique identifier for each chart and the type of the chart. If I get some time I'll create a smaller exmaple to directly reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was sort of hoping that when I posted this example that someone would recognise the corruption as a known issue. I'm not expecting anyone to spend time trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be related, but you can replace `_calculateleastDiff` with the following.

```
def _calculateleastDiff(self, xValues):
    return np.min(np.diff(sorted(xValues)))
```

This code is *way* over complicated for what it does.  I suspect you could get rid of both the `TChart` and `TPlot` classes.  I would keep a list of lists of data (so `[ [subplot1_data1,subplot1_data2],[subplot2_data1],[...]]`) a list of `axes` objects, and a list of something to keep track of what type of plot you want.

Also, try not to use names that are already used in matplotlib, it makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't think it's that over complicated. The context of the class is to provide quite a lot of functionality. We need to be able to dynamically add and delete plots, supplement data onto already existing charts and update on the fly already existing data. There may be a more efficient way than redrawing all the charts each time new data is added (not refreshed) but this is not required. All far I can tell all the data in the two supplementary classes is required. A list of lists could be regarded as not very OOP. I agree that for example code that it's on the long side.

Comment: I am hesitant to add examples of usage as I don't want to code bloat the question. I will maybe try and get a smaller example that displays the problem. Remeber this calss is integrated into a large application.

Comment: @user1904032 Is your goal to write ideologically pure OOP code, or readable code that works? When your classes have no methods and only attributes, you are essentially doing the list of lists thing, but wrapping the inner layer with a trivial object.  Also consider that `matplotlib` is already very nicely abstracted and OOP, leverage that instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Yeah you've a point but I don't really want to go further with this pedantry. If you can't help me with the question but only pick holes in subjective style then I'm not exactly progressing. I accept that I should have reduced the problem down a bit and that I'm not exactly encapsulating my data. I've also explained my requirements. The main problem is not how I implemented these requirements; rather it's what is explained in my initial post. I suggest you back and reread it and if you can offer a solution to the corruption I will appreciate it. Have a nice day.

Comment: BTW. I will be replacing calculateleastDiff with your alternative, so thanks for that. :) I''ve only a few days experience with this library so I suppose I'd be open to suggestions as to how to achieve my requirements using MATPLOTLIB's API. However, the corruption is my priority issue ATM.